# How to run a Custom Sharepoint Timer Job on alternate day?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, timer-jobs, sharepoint-timer-job

I have to perform some action using Custom Timer Job on **alternate day?**
Code to Create and start Timer job(in feature receiver) below,but it runs daily and **i have to run it on alternate days**?

How to do it?

private bool CreateJob(SPSite site)
        {
            bool jobCreated = false;
            try
            {

```
            TimerJob job = new TimerJob(JobName, site.WebApplication);
            job.Title = JobName;
            SPMinuteSchedule schedule = new SPMinuteSchedule();
            schedule.BeginSecond = 0;
            schedule.EndSecond = 59;
            schedule.Interval = 15;
            job.Schedule = schedule;

            job.Update();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return jobCreated;
        }
        return jobCreated;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the code above run every **15 minute**, you have **SPMinuteSchedule**, you must use **SPDailySchedule**. See [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spschedule(v=office.15).aspx)

However when Job run you can get the current DayOfWeek and run your code when you want

```
        switch (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek)
        {
            case DayOfWeek.Friday:
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Monday:
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Or you can save inside Job **Property Bag** the last run.
At [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.properties.aspx) you can find an example for SPWeb but is the same for SPJob.